# Listing Program exe names in C#?

Tags: c#, string

Ok, i am using this code to get all the installed programs on the users machine.

```
string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
        using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey))
        {
            foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(sk.GetValue("DisplayName"));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

All of the programs are listed in a listbox. How do i get the "programName".exe of that program. Like calculator is calc.exe ( i want the calc, but not the .exe ) How do i do that?

I am doing this so i can say:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exeName);
```

Comment: You don't need to trim off the .exe to run a command.

Comment: If you just want to get the file name without the extension, use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use TrimEnd

```
listBox1.Items.Add(sk.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString().TrimEnd(".exe".ToCharArray()));
```

EDIT:

To start a program from `System.Diagnostic.Process.Start`, you don't need to trim off ".exe", you can leave it as it and it will exectue

Comment: ok, thanks, but what if the name is not the exe name...like calculator?

Comment: if it is just "calculator", you will get calculator as returned value, because there is no ".exe" to trim

Comment: string name = sk.GetValue("name"); listBox1.Items.Add(name.Substring(0, name.LastIndexOf('.')));

Comment: @EliteGamer, my bad, TrimEnd requires character or character array, check the edited answer

Comment: @Habib.OSU look at my code on the bottom....if calculator is put in where exeName is, then it will not work. It has to be calc .... how do i fix that?

Comment: @EliteGamer, I am not sure about one thing, does "DisplayName" gives you the executable file name or program name ? for example in case of calc.exe, you will get what ? "calc.exe" or "Calculator"

Comment: Use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension) instead of `TrimEnd`.

Comment: @MetroSmurf, its not the file names, its just some string fields from the registry

Comment: Doesn't matter; a file name is still just a string. Path.x can be used on anything, not just File objects. Unless I'm missing something, the question is: "Like calculator is calc.exe (i want the calc, but not the .exe) How do i do that?" Rather than re-inventing something that is part of the framework, use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`